# Matching points to polygons and handling points NOT in polygons

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have two GeoDataFrames: one with 191k address points and another with 18 polygons representing catchment areas for specific schools. Theoretically, every address should fall into one of the zones.

When running my code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (191888) does not match length of index (191921)
```

I suspect that there are 33 points that are not matched to a polygon.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import os

from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon


pointpath = "/path/to/address points/"
point_df = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(pointpath,"addresses.shp"))


shapepath = "/path/to/catchment areas/"
shape_df = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(shapepath,"catchments.shp"))


school_list = []
for i in range(len(point_df)):
    pt = Point(point_df['geometry'][i])
    for index, row in shape_df.iterrows():
        poly = Polygon(row['geometry'])
        if(pt.within(poly)):
            school_list.append(row['school_name'])
            print(i)
point_df['zoned school']=school_list
point_df.to_excel(os.path.join(pointpath,'foo.xlsx'))
```

First off, is this the most efficient way of performing this task?

Second, is there a way to loop through the catchment areas and if there is no match, enter something like "no match found" so that the number of list items matches the number of dataframe rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [spatial join](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html#geopandas-sjoin) to join polygons to points:

```
import os.path
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas.tools import sjoin

pointpath = shapepath = "/tmp"

point_df = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(pointpath,"addresses.shp"))
shape_df = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(shapepath,"catchments.shp"))

join_left_df = sjoin(point_df, shape_df, how="left")
join_left_df  # Show all points, note the NaNs where the point did not intersect a poly

no_match_df = join_left_df.loc[join_left_df.index_right.isna()]
no_match_df # Show points that did not intersect a poly

join_inner_df = sjoin(point_df, shape_df, how="inner")
join_inner_df
# Show only points that intersect a poly
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure but could you not select by location:

```
processing.run("qgis:selectbylocation", {'INPUT': point_df, 'INTERSECT': shape_df, 
'METHOD': 0, 'PREDICATE': [6]})
```

should be something like that - if its not right, try doing it manually then click 'log' to see the parameters. I guess that would select all but the 33 you're after?