# Accessing polygon geometries from a geodataframe - keep getting a key error

Tags: python, keyerror

I have two geodataframes. One of about 5000 points (geolocated by me using GoogleV3, and one of 25000 polygons (from a govt-provided shapefile).

Every point will be in one (and unless only one) polygon. I would like to identify which polygon the point is in.

I am struggling to conceptualize how to do this, particularly as I cannot seem to access the 'geometry' column of the geodataframe that was imported by the shapefile.

For example, if I call

```
foo = offices.loc[3,'geometry']
```

I get a point: the coordinates of the 4th item in the GDF.

However, if I call

```
bar = zones.loc[3,'geometry']
```

I get a KeyError

```
bar = zones.loc[3,'geometry']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Geolocating/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1625, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1632, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 3


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-8f543fae5979>", line 1, in <module>
    bar = zones.loc[3,'geometry']

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Geolocating/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 889, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Geolocating/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1060, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Geolocating/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 807, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Geolocating/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1124, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Geolocating/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1073, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Geolocating/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3739, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Geolocating/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 3
```

I have no idea where to even begin, since I can't access specific rows to check if the point is within the polygon.

Comment: `.loc` is a label, not an elementwise position. To access rows by position, use `.iloc`.  Regardless, doing this row by row is probably not the best way. Try using a [spatial join](https://geopandas.org/gallery/spatial_joins.html).

Comment: [Here's how](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396892/2856) to do a spatial join

Comment: The spatial join worked perfectly - thanks